# Subdomains pointing to a wildcard folder

Tags: apache-2.2

I recently got my domain name working fine with my server and managed to get subdomains pointing to specific folders. However I have just noticed a little problem. I have my `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default` set to:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        VirtualDocumentRoot /local/www/%1
        ServerName *.dev.localhost
</VirtualHost>
```

and when I go to `test.dev.mydomain.co.uk` it displays the content of `/local/www/test/` and that's great. However, I mistyped the domain and realise that `test.mydomain.co.uk` is also doing the exact same thing when you miss out the `.dev.`part. I don't want this to happen. Can anybody suggest any fixes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the question:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    VirtualDocumentRoot /local/www/%1
    ServerName dev.mydomain.co.uk
    ServerAlias dev.mydomain.co.uk *.dev.mydomain.co.uk
</VirtualHost>
```

By using ServerAlias.

Answer (score 2):

If...

- The `VirtualHost` block above is the first one in your configuration, *and*
- There is no explicit match for, e.g., `test.mydomain.co.uk`

...then Apache will use the above `VirtualHost` block for `test.mydomain.co.uk`.  That is, in the absence of an explicit match, Apache will use the first `VirtualHost` definition it finds.  From [the documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/vhosts/name-based.html):

> If no matching ServerName or ServerAlias is found in the set of virtual hosts containing the most specific matching IP address and port combination, then the first listed virtual host that matches that will be used.

Comment: But I do have another `VirtualHost` block directly above it yet it's not taking that one on.

Comment: Well, then this probably isn't the problem.  What does the previous `VirtualHost` block look like?

Comment: It's one that makes `vps.mydomain.co.uk` point to `/local/www/static`